# Query the NetAdapter on Multiple Machines

Tags: powershell, active-directory

#Listing machine from which we will Query

```
$Machines = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase 'OU=Laptops,OU=Win10Modern,OU=LN,OU=Workstations,DC=cooley,DC=com' | Select-Object Name


#Getting the Network Adapter version for Wi-Fi Adapter

ForEach ($Machine in $Machines) {

 Get-NetAdapter | Select-Object Name,InterfaceDescription,DriverVersion,DriverDate,DriverProvider
 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You're expected to ask _questions_, so... what's the question here? :-)

Comment: I'm not getting the results i want. can someone help. i want to Get machines from an OU then for each, get the NetVersion of the Wifi Adapter

Comment: Please [update you post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68860992/edit) with any relevant details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, your code loops over **objects** in variable `$Machines`, where each object has a single property called `Name`.

In order to get just the name **values**, either use `Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name` or get the array of names like this:

```
# get an array of computernames
$Machines = (Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase 'OU=Laptops,OU=Win10Modern,OU=LN,OU=Workstations,DC=cooley,DC=com').Name
```

Next loop over these computernames and have each computer run the `Get-NetAdapter` cmdlet:

```
# capture the output(s) in variable $result
$result = foreach ($Machine in $Machines) {
    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $Machine -Count 1 -Quiet) {
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Machine -ScriptBlock {
            Get-NetAdapter | Select-Object SystemName,Name,InterfaceDescription,
                             DriverVersion,DriverDate,DriverProvider,Status,AdminStatus
        }
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "Computer '$Machine' does not respond"
    }
} 

# output on screen
$result

# or to GridView
$result | Out-GridView -Title 'NetAdapterInfo'

# or to CSV file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'X:\NetAdapterInfo.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

<sup>`AdminStatus` is a setting (enabled --> 'up'; disabled --> 'down')

`Status` is operational status (connected --> 'up'; disconnected --> 'down')</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use `Get-NetAdapter` to connect to remote computers.

You can however use `Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapter -ComputerName` .

Like this:

```
ForEach ($Machine in $Machines) {

    Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapter -Filter "NetConnectionStatus = 2" -ComputerName $Machine
 
}
```

You need to become familiar with the properties of the Win32_NetworkAdapter class. You can see all of the properties by running this command:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapter -ComputerName "Localhost" | fl * -Force
```

or you can use this command to see all of the properties (and methods) available to you.

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapter -ComputerName "Localhost" | Get-Member
```

Most computers will have more than 1 network card (some are hidden) and you have to filter the irrelevant ones out.

Comment: You can invoke the command over to the machine. May I also suggest using `Get-CimInstance,` as well.

Comment: Thanks Judd, how do i filter out the irrelevant ones. I'm still learning your help will be much appreciated

Comment: ```gwmi -Class 'Win32_NetworkAdapter' -Filter "NetConnectionStatus = 2" -ComputerName $Machine```

Comment: It appears there is no version property in Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapter